# How to execute sql file in query in mysql npm package

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a sql file dump of mysql db say reset.sql

I need to run it to restore the db

how can I execute the SQL file  inside `connection.query();` in mysql npm package?

```
 var mysql = require('mysql');
 var connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host:'********',
   user:'*****',
   password:'********',
   database:'***********'
   });

function selectQuery() {
    connection.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
          return;
        }
        console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
      });
     connection.query();
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
 var connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host:'********',
   user:'*****',
   password:'********',
   database:'***********'
   });

// for connection
    connection.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
          return;
        }
        console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
      });

// Function to perform the sql operation you want   
function reset(callback){
   connection.query("your sql query",function(err,out){
     if(err) callback(err,null);
     else callback(null,out)
})
}
```

Comment: I dont want to write the sql query here. I have a sql file in that all the queries are there.  I want to execute the reset.sql file directly instead of manually writing queries